# Python: How to specify/adjust folium heatmap gradient range

Tags: python-3.x, visualization, markerclusterer, folium

Hi I have created a simple heatmap using folium and would like to adjust the gradient/color of the heatmap. I have tried to play with the gradient feature in folium by using the code shown below

```
import folium
from folium import plugins
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import os

data =[[    40.7726,    -73.9568,   1900.    ],
       [    40.7785,    -73.9556,   3200.    ],
       [    40.7216,    -73.9809,   5800.    ],
       [    40.7384,    -73.9848,   2900.    ],
       [    40.7678,    -73.9915,   3312.    ],
       [    40.7659,    -73.9574,   2600.    ],
       [    40.7092,    -74.0137,   4299.    ],
       [    40.7384,    -73.982 ,   5750.    ],
       [    40.7312,    -73.9896,   3595.    ]]

m = folium.Map([40.7726,    -73.9568], 
               control_scale = True, zoom_start=11)

plugins.HeatMap(data, radius = 20, min_opacity = 0.1, max_val = 50,gradient={.6: 'blue', .98: 'lime', 1: 'red'}).add_to(m)
```

However, the effects isn't what I expected it to be. When plotting on a heatmap I will get something like the image shown below

[image]

For instance maybe the range to get Red requires a cluster of 20 but I would like to change this to maybe a cluster of 10 in order to be red. Is this possible with Folium?

Additionally, I would like to also plot the heatmap according to it's weights. For example, I can have two points one with a weight of 1900 and the other with 5800, I would like the 5800 to glow red while the weight of 1900 is yellow.

Answer (score 1):

Your use of the feature gradient in

```
plugins.HeatMap(data, radius = 20, min_opacity = 0.1, max_val = 50,gradient={.6: 'blue', .98: 'lime', 1: 'red'}).add_to(m)
```

is correct but there is bug in Leaflet on which Folium is relying on:

https://github.com/python-visualization/folium/issues/496